# LaTeX XY positioning

Tags: macros, positioning

I have not been using latex in a while and I would like to try to implement the tips & tricks given in this video during the TUG conference by Jean Luc Doumont : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkBCeOBbAmM

I tried to implement the first trick: xy positioning

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\def\xy#1#2#3{\setbox0=\hbox to\z@{%
\kern#1\raise#2\hbox{#3}\hss}%
\ht0=\z@\dp0=\z@\box0}


%testing the command
\xy 1 5 b


\end{document}
```

unfortunately I get the following error log

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\xy #1#2#3->\setbox 0=\hbox to\z 
                                 @{\kern #1\raise #2\hbox {#3}\hss }\ht 0=\z...
l.29 \xy 1 5 b

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   @
l.29 \xy 1 5 b

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   @
l.29 \xy 1 5 b

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   @
l.29 \xy 1 5 b

A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \raise 
l.29 \xy 1 5 b

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \hbox 
l.29 \xy 1 5 b

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Undefined control sequence.
\xy ...{\kern #1\raise #2\hbox {#3}\hss }\ht 0=\z 
                                                  @\dp 0=\z @\box 0
l.29 \xy 1 5 b

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   @
l.29 \xy 1 5 b

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   @
l.29 \xy 1 5 b

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Undefined control sequence.
\xy ...raise #2\hbox {#3}\hss }\ht 0=\z @\dp 0=\z 
                                                  @\box 0
l.29 \xy 1 5 b

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   @
l.29 \xy 1 5 b

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   @
l.29 \xy 1 5 b

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.32 \end{document}
```

and I can't figure out what is the mistake since I never programmed macros before.

Comment: Enclose the macro definition in `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. See [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/323) for details

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Before reinventing the wheel, you might want to take a look at the `picture` environment with its `\put` macro.

Comment: Just use tikz :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enclose the definition pf `\xy` inside `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother` due to the `@` character (See [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/3954)); also, in ots present form, the first and second arguments should be lengths (numbers plus a valid unit), and not simply numbers:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\xy#1#2#3{\setbox0=\hbox to\z@{%
\kern#1\raise#2\hbox{#3}\hss}%
\ht0=\z@\dp0=\z@\box0}
\makeatother

%testing the command
\xy{1cm}{-5cm}{b}


\end{document}
```

If you want the first two arguments to be numbers instead of lengths, you could say (as **percusse** suggested in a comment):

```
\makeatletter
\def\xy#1#2#3{{\setbox0=\hbox to\z@{%
\kern#1\p@\raise#2\p@\hbox{#3}\hss}%
\ht0=\z@\dp0=\z@\box0}}
\makeatother
```

(the unit is now `pt`) and then use `\xy` in the form

```
\xy{10}{-70}{b}
```

Notice also the braces enclosing the definition; this grouping will prevent problems that might occur when used in other macros (suggestion by **Heiko Oberdiek**).

Comment: I think appending `\p@` to `#1` and `#2` is a plausable shortcut to avoid the explicit dimensions.

Comment: A space after `\box0` prevents the macro from looking for further digits. Even is box 0 is a scratch register I would put it in a group to avoid trouble with the internals of other macros.

Comment: @percusse I incorporated your suggestion to my answer.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I incorporated your suggestion to my answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The group should start before `\setbox` and not before `\box`; in this way you're doing all the business in a group which doesn't influence possibly existent incarnations of `\box0`.

Comment: @egreg hehe... right. I'll fix it right now. Thank you!