# Package to design page on a grid layout (JL Doumont approach)

Tags: grid-typesetting

I am really thrilled by JL Doumont approach re the design of a page layout based on a grid system as detailed in his talk (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkBCeOBbAmM). I started to think about using this approach for my CV. I have found a post discussing this approach ([LaTeX XY positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110383/latex-xy-positioning)) based on the command detailed in the talk.

As I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I was wondering if someone knows a package that implements this strategy. Alternatively, does anyone know a full document (can be as small as 2 pages long) that implements this strategy and can be used as example ?

Comment: Is [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110383/latex-xy-positioning) your question?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/94380#94380, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/185536#185536.

Comment: indeed @cfr, the related link are the right ones. However, I am looking for a at least two pages long document that implements this strategy if possible